# Quotient of the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,m)=\langle a,b| bab^{-1}=a^m\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I would like to prove that in any non-trivial quotient of the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,m)$ defined by,
$$BS(1,m)=\langle a,b| bab^{-1}=a^m\rangle$$
the image of one of the generators $a$ or $b$ (by the canonical projection) have finite order. I only know that $BS(1,m)$ is solvable but I don't know if it will help me to prove the statement.
By advance thank you. Edgar.

Comment: I don't think $m$ needs to be prime, it's just an integer. By the way how do you prove that $BS(1, 2)$ is a quotient of $BS(1, 4)$? If my statement is true, then what is the order of the images of the generators of $BS(1, 4)$ in $BS(1, 2)$?

Comment: I think this is more suitable for MSE. let $N = \langle a^G \rangle$ be the normal closure of $a$. Every element of $N$ is conjugate to a power of $a$, so if you factor out an element of $N$ then you reduce $a$ to finite order. Otherwise, you factor out $b^kn$ for some $k \ne 0$ and $n \in N$, but $b^k$ does not centralize any element of $N$ (you do need to assume that $m \ne \pm 1$), so that would force $n=1$.

Comment: @Derek Thanks - I was too hasty. I've deleted both my comments.

Comment: @Derek Why is every element of $N$ conjugate to a power of $a$? For example, $b^{-1}aba^m\in N$, and by the conjugacy theorem for HNN-extensions we would need that $a^ib^{-1}aba^j=a^k$, which does not hold. No?

Comment: @user1729 Of course, I meant conjugate in $G={\rm BS}(1,m)$ to a power of $a$. Then $b(b^{-1}aba^m)b^{-1} = a^{m^2+1}$.

Comment: It is helpful to know that $N = \langle a^G \rangle$ is abelian and is isomorphic to the additive group of rational numbers of the form $im^j$ with $i,j \in {\mathbb Z}$, where the action of $b$ on $N$ by conjugation is multiplication by $m$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks. There are several points I don't understand. Firstly I don't see why your explanation in using $N$ proves that for ANY quotient of $G$, the image of $a$ or the image of $b$ have finite order. Then I don't understand why the elements of $G$ that are not in $N$ have the form $b^kn$ for $k\neq0$ and $n\in N$. I also think even if $m=-1$, then $b^k$ doesn't centralize $a$.

Comment: OK, I'll answer the question with more detail.

Comment: @Derek Thanks. Again, I was too hasty!

Answer (score 7):

First note that the result is false when $m = 1$, because $G$ is just free abelian of rank $2$ in that case, and the subgroup $K=\langle ab \rangle$ is normal but neither $a$ nor $b$ has finite order $G/K$. So assume that $m \ne 1$. Also, if $m=0$ then $a=1$, so we can assume $m \ne 0$.

For $k \in {\mathbb Z}$, let $a_k = b^kab^{-k}$. So $a=a_0$ and, for all $k \in {\mathbb Z}$, $a_{k+1} = b^{k}bab^{-1}b^{-k} = b^ka^mb^{-k} = a_k^m$.

So, if we let $N = \langle a_k \mid k \in {\mathbb Z} \rangle$, then since $a_l$ is a power of $a_k$ whenever $l \ge k$, any pair of generators of $N$ commute, and hence $N$ is abelian. (It is not hard to see that the map $a_k \mapsto m^k$ induces an isomorphism from $N$ to the additive group of rationals of the form $jm^k$ for $j,k \in {\mathbb Z}$.)

Also, $N$ is centralized by $a=a_0$ and normalized by $b$, so it is normal in $G$ and is in fact the normal closure $\langle a^G \rangle$ of $a$ in $G$.

By putting $a=1$ in the presentation, we see that $G/N$ is infinite cyclic and generated by the image of $b$, so $G$ is the semidirect product $N \rtimes \langle b \rangle$, where $b$ acts on $N$ by mapping $a_k$ to $a_{k+1}$.

Now, since $a_k^m=a_{k+1}$, we can write each element of $N$ as a power of $a_k$ for some fixed $k$. Since $b^{-k}a_kb^k = a_0=a$, we see that every element of $N$ is conjugate in $G$ to a power of $a$.

Now let $K$ be any nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$. If $K \cap N \ne 1$ then, as we just saw, $N \cap K$ contains a nontrivial power of $a$, and so the image of $a$ in $G/K$ has finite order.

Otherwise, since $G = N\langle b \rangle$, $N$ contains an element $nb^j$ for some $n \in N$ with $j > 0$. If $n=1$, then the image of $b$ has finite order in $G/K$. Otherwise, since we are assuming $m \ne 1$, $b$ does not centralize $n$, so the commutator $[b,nb^j]$ is a nontrivial element of $N \cap K$, and we are back in the previous case.