# Showing affine transformations group generated by $2x$ and $x+1$ is the Baumslag-Solitar group.

Tags: group-theory, affine-geometry, group-presentation

> I want to compute the presentation groups of $\langle f,g\rangle$ the generated group of affine transformations with $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x+1.$
>
> The affirmation is $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}=b^2\rangle$ the [Baumslag-Solitar group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group).

I have this:

For any $h\in \langle f,g\rangle, h(x)=2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}$ with $n,m,k$ integers.
And, the word $f^{-k}g^{m}f^{k+n}$ is associated with $2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}$, because $f^{-k}\circ g^{m}\circ f^{k+n}(x)=2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}.$

I know that exists $\varphi:F(S)=\left\{f,g,f^{-1},g^{-1}\right\}^{\ast}\to \langle f,g\rangle$ epimorphism.

I want to prove that $\ker\varphi=\langle \langle T\rangle\rangle$ with $T=\left\{fgf^{-1}g^{-2}\right\}$.

Obviously $\langle \langle T\rangle\rangle\subset \ker\varphi$ because $fgf^{-1}g^{-2}(x)=Id(x)$ then $\varphi(fgf^{-1}g^{-2})=Id_{\langle f,g\rangle }$.

> But, how to prove that $\ker\varphi\subset \langle \langle T\rangle\rangle$?

Comment: Isn't it enough for you to prove that both functions have infinite order and they fulfill $\;f\circ g\circ f^{-1}=g^{2}\;$ ?

Comment: $fgg=g^{-1} $ is $f=g^{-3}$ but $2x\neq x-3$...

Comment: Read again the comment...

Comment: What happens is that I need to prove that $<f, g> = <f,g|fgf^{-1}=g^{-2}>$ and that happens when $\ker \varphi = << T >>$

Comment: As far as I see it, you only need to show $\;f,g\;$ fulfill that condition and they both are of infinite order. Then, from a free group on two generators you'd get the very same homomorphism than to the Baumslag-Solitar Group above. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @DonAntonio: that just shows this group is a quotient of the BS group.

Comment: @DonAntonio: or perhaps you are relying on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1308040/320311)?

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: Note that DonAntonio's comments together with Hempelicious's link solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, i have this:

$\varphi:\left\{a,b\right\}\to <f,g>$ with $\varphi(a)=f$ and $\varphi(b)=g$ homomorphism.

exists unique epimorphism $\varphi F(a,b)\to <f,g>$ such that
$\varphi(w)=w$ with $w$ word in Domain, and $w$ group element in Codomain.

further, $F(a,b)/\ker\varphi\simeq <f,g>$.

Afirmation. $\ker\varphi=<< aba^{-1}b^{-2}>>$.
Obviously $<< aba^{-1}b^{-2}>>\subset \ker\varphi$.

Now, let $w\in \ker\varphi$, then $w=a^{-k}b^{m}a^{k+n}$ with 
$\varphi(a^{-k}b^{m}a^{k+n})=Id$, or, equivalent, $2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}=x$, and this implies $n=m=0$.

Therefore, $w\sim a^{-k}a^{k}\sim \epsilon\sim aba^{-1}b^{-2}\in <<aba^{-1}b^{-2}>>$.

Therefore $\ker\varphi=<<aba^{-1}b^{-2}>>$

It is correct?

Comment: Why are you sure $w$ has that form??

Comment: That is because  all element inf $<f,g>$ is of the form  $2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}$ and  $\varphi(a^{-k}b^ma^{k+n})=2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}$

Comment: But why does *any* $w\in\ker\phi$ have that form? You need to prove that!

Comment: I tried that any $h\in <f,g>,\ h=2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}$ and $f^{-k}g^{m}f^{k+n}(x)=2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}.$

Identifying $a$ by $f$ and $b$ by $g$ I have, and $\varphi:F(a,b)\to <f,g>$ epimorphism.
For any, $h\in <f,g>$ exists $a^{-k}b^{m}a^{k+n}\in F(a,b) : \varphi(a^{-k}b^{m}a^{k+n})=h$.

This requires that
 any word of $F(a,b)$, is $w=a^{-k}b^{m}a^{k+n}$ because $\varphi(w)\in <f,g>$ then $\varphi(w)=2^nx+\frac{m}{2^k}$

In particular, any word in $\ker\varphi$ is of the form $a^{-k}b^{m}a^{k+n}$.

or not?

Comment: In the event that my previous comment was wrong.
How can I prove that every word in $<a, b | aba = b^2>$ is of the form $a^{- k} b^{m} a^{k + n}$?

Comment: It is not true every word in $F(a,b)$ is of that form ($abab$ for example). But it **is** true in the Baumslag Solitar group. This follows from $ab=b^2a$ and $a^{-1}b=(a^{-1}ba)a^{-1}$ and the fact the normal subgroup generated by $b$ is abelian.

Comment: Why normal subgroup generated by $b$ is abelian?
$(hbh^{-1})(h'b{h'}^{-1})=(h'b{h'}^{-1})(hbh^{-1})$?

Comment: it is enough to show any two elements are in a cyclic subgroup together. Consider $x=a^{-r}b^ma^r$ and $y=a^{-s}b^na^s$. If $r>s$, then  with $z=a^{-r}ba^r$, $x=z^m$ and y=$(a^{r-s}za^{s-r})^n=z^t$, with $t=2^{r-s}n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution. From the set mapping
\begin{align*}
a&\mapsto f\\
b&\mapsto g
\end{align*}

There is a group homomorphism $F=\langle a,b\mid\rangle\rightarrow G=\langle f,g\rangle$. Let $K$ be the kernel of this map, so that $F/K\cong G$.

Since $aba^{-1}b^{-2}\in K$, we can let $N$ be the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by it.  Then $(F/N)/(K/N)\cong G$.

In $F/N$, we have $\bar{a}\bar{b}=\bar{b}^2\bar{a}$, from the relation $aba^{-1}b^{-2}\in N$. Thus every element of $F/N$ can be written as $\bar{b}^n\bar{a}^m$.

If $\bar{b}^n\bar{a}^m\in K/N$, then $g^n\circ f^m$ is the identity map.  But
$$ g^n\circ f^m(x) = 2^mx+n$$
which is only the identity map if $m=n=0$. So $K/N$ only has the trivial element, so that $K=N$.  This means $F/N\cong G$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: It is not true that every element of $F/N$ can be written as $\bar{b}^n\bar{a}^m$ for integers $m$ and $n$. For example $\bar{a}^{-1}\bar{ b}\bar{     a}$ cannot be written in that form (unless you are allowing $n$ to be a fraction).

Comment: @DerekHolt: yes you're right! I was thinking of $F/N$ as the semidirect product with the dyadic rational, but that didn't come through in my write-up. I'll update when I get a chance, thanks.

Comment: It is true that every element can be written as $a^{-k}b^ma^{k+n}$ (as in eradcoil's proof) but that needs justifying. You can collect all the negative powers of $a$ to the left.

Comment: How can I prove that every element of $BS(1,2)$ is of the form $a^{-p}a^{s}b^{q}$ with $s \in\mathbb{Z} 
, p,q\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$?

I tried induction in the large of the word.
With the relations $ab=b^2a$ and $ba^{-1}=a^{-1}b^2$

For $a,b, ab,ab^{-1}, a^{-1}b, a^{-1}b^{-1}$ etc etc this is true

Let $w$ word in $BS(1,2)$ with the form $w=a^{-p}b^{s}a^{q}$
Let's prove that $wa, wb, wa^{-1}, wb^{-1}$ It has the same form.

Por example, $wb=(a^{-p}b^{s}a^{q})b$


Here I have a problem. For more than trying to play with relationships
I can not "move" that  $b$ to the "center"